# Kalman Filter (pykalman): Value for obs_covariance and model without intercept

Tags: transition, covariance, kalman-filter, pykalman

I am looking at the KalmanFilter from pykalman shown in examples:

[pykalman documentation](https://pykalman.github.io/)

[Example 1](http://mcai.trade/2017/11/26/Kalman-Filter/)

[Example 2](http://www.thealgoengineer.com/2014/online_linear_regression_kalman_filter/)

and I am wondering

```
observation_covariance=100,

vs

observation_covariance=1,
```

the documentation states

```
observation_covariance R: e(t)^2 ~ Gaussian (0, R)
```

How should the value be set here correctly?

Additionally, is it possible to apply the Kalman filter without intercept in the above module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observation covariance shows how much error you assume to be in your input data. Kalman filter works fine on normally distributed data. Under this assumption you can use the 3-Sigma rule to calculate the covariance (in this case the variance) of your observation based on the maximum error in the observation.

The values in your question can be interpreted as follows:

*Example 1*

```
observation_covariance = 100
sigma = sqrt(observation_covariance) = 10
max_error = 3*sigma = 30
```

*Example 2*

```
observation_covariance = 1
sigma = sqrt(observation_covariance) = 1
max_error = 3*sigma = 3
```

So you need to choose the value based on your observation data. **The more accurate the observation, the smaller the observation covariance.**

Another point: you can tune your filter by manipulating the covariance, but I think it's not a good idea. The higher the observation covariance value the weaker impact a new observation has on the filter state.

Sorry, I did not understand the second part of your question (about the Kalman Filter without intercept). Could you please explain what you mean?
You are trying to use a regression model and both intercept and slope belong to it.

**---------------------------**

**UPDATE**

I prepared some code and plots to answer your questions in details. I used EWC and EWA historical data to stay close to the original article.

First of all here is the code (pretty the same one as in the examples above but with a different notation)

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reading data (quick and dirty)
Datum=[]
EWA=[]
EWC=[]

for line in open('data/dataset.csv'):
    f1, f2, f3  = line.split(';')
    Datum.append(f1)
    EWA.append(float(f2))
    EWC.append(float(f3))

n = len(Datum)

# Filter Configuration

# both slope and intercept have to be estimated

# transition_matrix  
F = np.eye(2) # identity matrix because x_(k+1) = x_(k) + noise

# observation_matrix  
# H_k = [EWA_k   1]
H = np.vstack([np.matrix(EWA), np.ones((1, n))]).T[:, np.newaxis]

# transition_covariance 
Q = [[1e-4,     0], 
     [   0,  1e-4]] 

# observation_covariance 
R = 1 # max error = 3

# initial_state_mean
X0 = [0,
      0]

# initial_state_covariance
P0 = [[  1,    0], 
      [  0,    1]]

# Kalman-Filter initialization
kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=2,
                  transition_matrices = F, 
                  observation_matrices = H, 
                  transition_covariance = Q, 
                  observation_covariance = R, 
                  initial_state_mean = X0, 
                  initial_state_covariance = P0)

# Filtering
state_means, state_covs = kf.filter(EWC)

# Restore EWC based on EWA and estimated parameters
EWC_restored = np.multiply(EWA, state_means[:, 0]) + state_means[:, 1]    

# Plots
plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(state_means[:, 0], label="Slope")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(state_means[:, 1], label="Intercept")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

# check the result
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(EWC, label="EWC original")
plt.plot(EWC_restored, label="EWC restored")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

I could not retrieve data using pandas, so I downloaded them and read from the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iY_sztmfa0readyGWU_OoFu9hinRxJKv).

Here you can see the estimated slope and intercept:

[image: Linear regression using Kalman Filter. Both Slope and Intercept estimated]

To test the estimated data I restored the EWC value from the EWA using the estimated parameters:

[image: Original and restored function using estimated slope and interception]

**About the observation covariance value**

By varying the observation covariance value you tell the Filter how accurate the input data is (normally you just describe your confidence in the observation using some datasheets or your knowledge about the system).

Here are estimated parameters and the restored EWC values using different observation covariance values:

[image: slope and intercept using different observation covariance values]

[image: restored function using different observation covariance values]

You can see the filter follows the original function better with a bigger confidence in observation (smaller R). If the confidence is low (bigger R) the filter leaves the initial estimate (slope = 0, intercept = 0) very slowly and the restored function is far away from the original one.

**About the frozen intercept**

If you want to freeze the intercept for some reason, you need to change the whole model and all filter parameters.

In the normal case we had:

```
x = [slope; intercept]    #estimation state
H = [EWA    1]            #observation matrix
z = [EWC]                 #observation
```

Now we have:

```
x = [slope]               #estimation state
H = [EWA]                 #observation matrix
z = [EWC-const_intercept] #observation
```

Results:

[image: estimation with the constant intercept]

[image: restored function using the constant intercept]

Here is the code:

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# only slope has to be estimated (it will be manipulated by the constant intercept) - mathematically incorrect!
const_intercept = 10

# reading data (quick and dirty)
Datum=[]
EWA=[]
EWC=[]

for line in open('data/dataset.csv'):
    f1, f2, f3  = line.split(';')
    Datum.append(f1)
    EWA.append(float(f2))
    EWC.append(float(f3))

n = len(Datum)

# Filter Configuration

# transition_matrix  
F = 1 # identity matrix because x_(k+1) = x_(k) + noise

# observation_matrix  
# H_k = [EWA_k]
H = np.matrix(EWA).T[:, np.newaxis]

# transition_covariance 
Q = 1e-4 

# observation_covariance 
R = 1 # max error = 3

# initial_state_mean
X0 = 0

# initial_state_covariance
P0 = 1    

# Kalman-Filter initialization
kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=1,
                  transition_matrices = F, 
                  observation_matrices = H, 
                  transition_covariance = Q, 
                  observation_covariance = R, 
                  initial_state_mean = X0, 
                  initial_state_covariance = P0)

# Creating the observation based on EWC and the constant intercept
z = EWC[:] # copy the list (not just assign the reference!)
z[:] = [x - const_intercept for x in z]

# Filtering
state_means, state_covs = kf.filter(z) # the estimation for the EWC data minus constant intercept

# Restore EWC based on EWA and estimated parameters
EWC_restored = np.multiply(EWA, state_means[:, 0]) + const_intercept

# Plots
plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(state_means[:, 0], label="Slope")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(const_intercept*np.ones((n, 1)), label="Intercept")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

# check the result
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(EWC, label="EWC original")
plt.plot(EWC_restored, label="EWC restored")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you, Anton. Apologies, I don't get that part: You say the covariance is to be calculated using the 3*sigma rule, but in fact sigma depends on the covariance in beforehand? 
regarding question two: yes, that's what I wanted to know: to run a regression without intercept or only slope; the assumption is to include the premium in the beta (hedge ratio) to account for any premium when holding one asset against the other; but putting aside the theoretical assumption, what would I need to change? instead of adding the ones in the matrix I add zeros?

Comment: Sigma and covariance show the same property of the signal, but in different ways. In case of a normal distribution they both depend on the max error, because it's very close to the 3*sigma level (99.73%). Knowing the max error allows you to calculate sigma and covariance (in this case variance).

Comment: Regarding the second question, I need a bit time to reconstruct the problem. I would say by freezing the intercept you will manipulate the slope. So the result will probably make no sense.

Comment: thanks, Anton. in practical terms, do you have any suggestions to get the max error? I may need some more, since I am not seeing it yet.

Comment: forcing the the regression through the origin will affect the slope, no question. I was just wondering in terms of application, for a normal in-build OLS, I can specifiy with or without constant; however for the pykalman it's not so clear to me how to modify the matrices and then to compare results with and without intercept.

Comment: To estimate the max error you need to know your system very well. Normally the manufactorer of the sensor tells you how precise the sensor is (you are givven the sigma value). If you don't have such information you need to define the tolerance range by your self. If your scale tells you your weight is 80 kg, it is pretty impossible that your real weight is 20 or 140 kg, but it can lay between 75 and 85 kg. In this case you could estimate the max error to be 5 kg and the variance = (5/3)^2 kg^2.

Comment: thank you, Anton. So for instance, if a variable is assumed to be normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1, the max error = 3*sqrt(1) = 3 and vice versa, the covariance is 1 (which in this case is the variance itself)?

Comment: Exactly! If you want you can take the python code from my previous post and play around with the covariance value. The code plots a vehicle trajectory estimated in pykalman. The working dataset is also there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599886/kalman-filter-with-varying-timesteps

Comment: As soon as I have some code and plots for the linear regression problem, I'll update my answer here.

Comment: Have a look at my update. I think it is what you wanted to get, isn't it?

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, had some technical issues. 

Thank you for the great illustration, Anton! Excluding the intercept seems to overestimate my slope (which I expected), however, thinking of a intercept = 0, that would mean both series would "start" at zero. So assuming an intercept = 1, I indexed the time series, so both start at 1.