# How do I combine data from two sensors using an extended Kalman filter where one of the sensors is more reliable than the other?

Tags: filtering, data-analysis, kalman-filter, sensors

I've two sensors **A** and **B**. I'm trying to combine their sensor data using *Extended Kalman Filter* for a productive data analysis. Since the data types are non-linear, I'm using the *Extended Kalman filter*. In my case, the data from sensor **A** is always reliable however the reliability of data from sensor **B** varies on time. For example, at `t=0`, it's reliability is high and the reliability decreases gradually (uniformly) till `t=T`. In this situation, how can I combine the sensor data for a better-optimized result? Or how can I assign a dynamic weight (`t=0` to `t=T`) for data from the sensor **B** ?

**Update**: I have to use the data from sensor **B** in the prediction phase of the EKF.

Comment: You need a function which calculates the sensor reliability in terms of variance depending on time. Having one you can set the measurement covariance for each sensor. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599886/kalman-filter-with-varying-timesteps. In this implementation there are two sensors with different static variance. Your case is pretty the same, but the variance is a function of time.

Comment: I don't really understand your Update statement. Your filter would have only one measurement (for both sensors A and B) and only one state for the measured value. The filter will not even know that there are two sensors, the only thing it will see is that some measurements come with higher variance. The prediction phase does not care about sensors at all. It depends only on your system modelling and at the end on the F and Q matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've already mentioned in my comments you can express the reliability of your sensors through the input variance. The variance of Sensor A will be constant whereas the variance of Sensor B increases over the time.

The filter does not care how many sensors are in the system. It just gets measurements on its input as if there is only one sensor. The important thing is the communicated variance.

Here is a short matlab example of a filter with two acceleration sensors. The state space consists of the velocity and acceleration. Sensor A is active at even and Sensor B at odd calls.

```
function [] = main()

    dt = 0.01;
    t=(0:dt:70)';

    acc_ref = sin(0.3*t) + 0.5*sin(0.04*t);

    accA_std = 0.05; % standard deviation for Sensor A
    accB_std = 0.1 + 0.01*t; % standard deviation for Sensor B

    accA = acc_ref + randn(size(t)).*accA_std;
    accB = acc_ref + randn(size(t)).*accB_std;

    n = numel(t);

    % state matrix (velocity, acceleration)
    X = zeros(2,1);

    % covariance matrix
    P = diag([0.1, 0.1]);

    % system noise
    Q = diag([1, 0.02]);

    % transition matrix
    F = [1, dt; 
         0, 1]; 

    % observation matrix 
    H = [0 1];

    % measurement noise 
    R = 0; % will be set depending on sensor A or B

    % kalman filter output through the whole time
    X_arr = zeros(n, 2);

    % fusion
    for i = 1:n

        % use sensor A at even and B at odd calls
        if (mod(i, 2))
            y = accA(i);
            R = accA_std^2; %set varaince of Sensor A as measurement noise
        else
            y = accB(i);
            R = accB_std(i)^2; %set varaince of Sensor B as measurement noise
        end

        if (i == 1)
            [X] = init_kalman(X, y); % initialize the state using the 1st sensor
        else
            [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F);
            [X, P] = update(X, P, y, R, H);
        end

        X_arr(i, :) = X;
    end  

    figure;
    plot(t, acc_ref, 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on;
    plot(t, accA, 'LineWidth', 1);
    plot(t, accB, 'LineWidth', 1);
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 2), 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold off;
    grid on;
    legend('Ground Truth', 'SensorA', 'SensorB', 'Estimation');
end

function [X] = init_kalman(X, y)
    X(1) = 0;
    X(2) = y;
end

function [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F)
    X = F*X;
    P = F*P*F' + Q;
end

function [X, P] = update(X, P, y, R, H)
    Inn = y - H*X;
    S = H*P*H' + R;
    K = P*H'/S;

    X = X + K*Inn;
    P = P - K*H*P;
end
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Fusion of two acceleration sensors using Kalman Filter]

If your system proceeds both sensors in each call you need to execute the update phase twice:

```
for i = 1:n
    y1 = accA(i);
    R1 = accA_std^2; %set varaince of Sensor A as measurement noise

    y2 = accB(i);
    R2 = accB_std(i)^2; %set varaince of Sensor B as measurement noise

    if (i == 1)
        [X] = init_kalman(X, y1); % initialize the state using the 1st sensor
    else
        [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F);

        [X, P] = update(X, P, y1, R1, H); %Update for Sensor A
        [X, P] = update(X, P, y2, R2, H); %Update for Sensor B
    end

    X_arr(i, :) = X;
end
```

The result will be a little bit better, because the filter gets more information from the measurements:

[image: Fusion of the both sensors at one call]

Comment: Does the order of multiple updates matter?

Comment: The order doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to derive a proof for a pair of measurements but in vain. The best I could get is this hypothesized relationship: $$K2 (I + H K1) = K1$$, where K1, K2 are the 2 gains for the updates of the 1st and 2nd measurements. I can't algebraically proof that, but my code does suggest so. I'm wondering if it is so symmetric, is there a way to reduce multiple measures into one and do single equivalent update? Or, that would be too complex it is not worth the trouble?