# control matrix for opencv predict() in Kalman filter implementation for trajectory estimation?

Tags: opencv, kalman-filter

I am trying to estimate the position based on current position (x,y) and create a trajectory.For this I am using kalman filter.I am using opencv based kalman filter implementation in my code.I'm not getting info about what should I take value for 'control matrix' and 'control vector' to avoid collision case for this trajectory estimation based on position vector.

My Transition matrix is position [x,y], measurement matrix is position [x,y].Then what about control matrix? Can anybody help me out to get all these matrix value if I have only position [x,y] as input.

As I found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/src/kalman.cpp) , control we are passing to predict() function as argument but where it's updating ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you think you need the control matrix? just set it to a zero-matrix (at least for the beginning). The majority of Kalman-Filter examples doesn't involve the control matrix at all.

Comment: @Anton,My case is similar to [https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/using-kalman-filter-for-object-tracking.html]

Comment: Hi ,I want to use my kalman when detection lost.I don't want to use correct since start of frame when detection happening because I have some other algorithm for this and when object is lost then I want to enable kalman for tracking  and show.How can I approach it?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added an update to my post. Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest case you don't need a control matrix (to make it sure you need to provide more information on your model).

> My Transition matrix is position [x,y]

It sounds strange for me. I think you meant your state vector.
If so I would suggest you add more state variables to be able to predict you state during the prediction step. Depending on your system dynamic you could just add the  velocities (`vx`, `vy`) or maybe both velocities and accelerations (`vx`, `vy`, `ax`, `ay`).

Your state vector would look like

`x = [px py vx vy]'`

The state variables will be updated according to your transition matrix, even if you have no measurement for the velocities and accelerations.

Am example for an appropriate control vector in this case could be a reading from brakes (if you model a vehicle). Without knowing the brake force your system will predict the motion according to the velocity estimation to the current time step and will predict further moving although the system decelerates.

You can have a look at this post [Kalman filter with varying timesteps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599886/kalman-filter-with-varying-timesteps).
The filter has only measurements of X and Y position, but the state vector incorporates the velocities.

**UPDATE**

Assume your model needs a control input.

As seen in the OpenCV code, you have following functions in your Kalman Filter Library:

```
void KalmanFilter::init(int DP, int MP, int CP, int type)

const Mat& KalmanFilter::predict(const Mat& control)

const Mat& KalmanFilter::correct(const Mat& measurement)
```

To be able to use the control input you need to pass a correct matrix dimension `CP` when initializing the filter (zero would mean you don't have a control matrix).

Your Filtering Code would look like this:

```
init(...)

predict(...)
correct(...)

predict(...)
correct(...)

and so on
```

At each call you will get some measurements from your environment. If we stick with the vehicle example and involve break readings as a control input, then each time calling `predict()` you need to pass actual break force into the prediction function. If there is no break activity, the matrix will be empty and the control input will not be applied at the current call.

[Here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/113657/kalman-filter-assertion-failed-matrix-types/) you can see a code example with a control input. The guy had an error in his `init()` call (he initialized `CP=0` instead of `CP=3`) but the code looks ok.

For more help I need to know more about your model. From what you've posted so far I cannot see any need in control input.

**UPDATE**

To your question in the comments:

> I want to use my kalman when detection lost.I don't want to use
>   correct since start of frame when detection happening because I have
>   some other algorithm for this and when object is lost then I want to
>   enable kalman for tracking and show.How can I approach it?

Generally you have a free choice between kalman sub-functions `predict()` and `correct()` during the estimation. It depends on how your algorithm is triggered: with a constant call rate (let's say every 100ms) or on measurement event.

In the case of the constant call rate you check if you have an appropriate measurement and decide if you need a correction or not. If you don't need it you just perform `predict()`, otherwise `predict()`, `correct()`. So it's possible to have no corrections for a while.

If the filter is triggered through measurement events, you can perform `predict()` and `correct()` at each call, but you need to recalculate your `F` and `Q` matrices for the prediction depending on the time interval `dt` since last correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This info helps me to understand about it.

Comment: As you suggested I apply changes ,In my case, when object is detected in previous frame but not detected in the current frame, I'm assigning previous frame object state to kf.statePost then for 5 next frame , I am doing predict() ,correct() - I'm passing predicted state (as measurement ) to correct() and after 5 frame I'm only predicting for tracking of lost objects.But in result I found that there is no change in kf.statePost and kf.errorCovPost after correct() call that must be change in ideal case. Please correct if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: For this I would need your code. Can you post it somewhere? Maybe in GoogleDocs or something like this.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to post the source code because of some restrictions. Can you please write a pseudo code for the same. When detection lost and there is no actual object detected location,only we have last detected location.

Comment: I would suggest to put a new question on stackoverflow, so the community can help to solve it. Maybe you can describe the problem a little bit exactly there.